# Buddyboss Admin or moderator label show and title show

Tags: buddypress, buddyboss

I want to add a label side the user name who posted a post on groups or activity
the label will be admin or moderator
if A admin post it will show admin label or if the moderator post it will show the moderator label
i successfully added those label but it dissappear the group title from the activity header feed.
here is my c[enter image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7eNY.jpg) description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v5mC.jpg)

```
function custom_activity_action_string( $action, $activity ) {

    // Get the author role
    $author_role = bbp_get_user_display_role($activity->user_id);

    // Set the label based on user role
    if ( $author_role == 'Keymaster' ) {
        $label = '<span class="group-admin-label">Admin</span>';
    } elseif ( $author_role == 'Participant' ) {
        $label = '<span class="group-moderator-label">Moderator</span>';
    } else {
        $label = '';
    }

    // Check if activity is in group activity page or main activity page
    if ( $activity->component == 'groups' && $activity->type == 'activity_update' ) {
        $group_label = __( 'posted an update in the group', 'text-domain' );
    } else {
        $group_label = __( 'posted an update', 'text-domain' );
    }

    // Get user data
    $user_link = bp_core_get_userlink( $activity->user_id );
    $user_name = bp_core_get_user_displayname( $activity->user_id );
    
        // Get the activity ID
    $activity_id = bp_get_activity_id();

    // Get the group ID
    $group_id = bp_activity_get_meta( $activity_id, 'item_id', true );

    // Get the group title
    $group_title = bp_get_group_name( $group_id );

    // Get group data if activity is in group activity page
    if ( $activity->component == 'groups' ) {
        $group_link = bp_get_group_permalink( $activity->item_id );
        $group_avatar = bp_get_group_avatar_url( $activity->item_id, array( 'type' => 'full' ) ); // Replace this line with bp_get_group_logo_url to show the group logo
        $group_name = bp_get_group_name( $activity->item_id );
        $group_post_title = bp_activity_get_meta( $activity->id, 'bp_activity_title', true ); // Get the title of the post within the group

        // Set label based on group type
        $group_type = bp_get_group_type( $activity->item_id );
        if ( $group_type == 'hidden' ) {
            $group_label = __( 'posted an update in the private group', 'text-domain' );
        }
    }

    // Build activity action string
    $action = sprintf(
        __( '%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s', 'text-domain' ),
        $user_link,
        $label,
        $group_label,
        $group_title,
        isset( $group_avatar ) ? '<img src="' . $group_avatar . '" alt="' . $group_name . '"/>' : '',
        isset( $group_post_title ) ? $group_post_title : ''
    );

    // Add group name and link if activity is in group activity page
    if ( $activity->component == 'groups' ) {
        $action .= sprintf(
            __( ' %1$s', 'text-domain' ),
            '<a class ="grp-ttl" href="' . $group_link . '">group name' . $group_name . $group_title . '</a>',
            
        );
    }

    return $action;
}
add_filter( 'bp_get_activity_action_pre_meta', 'custom_activity_action_string', 10, 2 );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZAIm.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OkhX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code full code

```html
function custom_activity_action_string( $action, $activity ) {

    // Get the author role
    $author_role = bbp_get_user_display_role($activity->user_id);
    $author_id = bp_get_activity_user_id();

     // Get the group ID
    $group_id = bp_get_activity_item_id();
    // Get the User ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    
    
// Set the label based on user role
    if ( groups_is_user_admin( $author_id, $group_id ) ) {
        $label = '<span class="group-admin-label">Admin</span>';
    } elseif ( groups_is_user_mod( $author_id, $group_id ) ) {
        $label = '<span class="group-moderator-label">Moderator</span>';
    } elseif ( groups_is_user_member( $author_id, $group_id ) ) {
        $label = '';
    } else {
        $label = '';
    }
    
    
// for show the user role for a group
//  if ($author_role){
//      $label = '<span class="author-role">' . $author_role . '</span>';
//  }
    
    // Check if activity is in group activity page or main activity page
    if ( $activity->component == 'groups' && $activity->type == 'activity_update' ) {
        $group_label = __( 'posted an update in the group', 'text-domain' );
    } else {
        $group_label = __( 'posted an update', 'text-domain' );
    }

    // Get user data
    $user_link = bp_core_get_userlink( $activity->user_id );
    $user_name = bp_core_get_user_displayname( $activity->user_id );


    // Get the group ID
    $group_id = bp_get_activity_item_id();
    
    // Get the group object
    $group = groups_get_group( array( 'group_id' => $group_id ) );
    
    // Get the group title and link
    $group_title = $group->name;
    $group_link = bp_get_group_permalink( $group );

        // Set label based on group type
        $group_type = bp_get_group_type( $activity->item_id );
        if ( $group_type == 'hidden' ) {
            $group_label = __( 'posted an update in the private group', 'text-domain' );
        }

    // Build activity action string 
    $action = sprintf(
        __( '%1$s %2$s %3$s', 'text-domain' ),
        $user_link,
        $label,
        $group_label,
    );

    // Add group name and link if activity is in group activity page    
    if ( $activity->component == 'groups' ) {
        $action .= sprintf(
            __( ' <a class ="grp-ttl" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', 'text-domain' ),
            $group_link,
            $group_title
        );
    }

    return $action;
}
add_filter( 'bp_get_activity_action_pre_meta', 'custom_activity_action_string', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).